# Web Server Logs for Function App in both Consumption & App Service Plan

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have created two function Apps with a few Functions in it (Http,Queue triggers etc), one in Consumption and the other in App Service Plan. However, i don't see any logs in the Web Server Logs section of the Log Stream in both my Function Apps.

It always shows the following.

[image]

Can someone help me in understanding if this feature available for Function Apps?

Thanks,
Praveen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Log streaming, Application logs is able to see all Azure Functions logs, including host and functions entries. Web Server logs seems not useful in Azure Function and no log is written there.

Go to kudu(`https://functionappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`) and navigate to `D:\home\LogFiles` to check. Subfolder `Application` is Application logs and `http` is Web Server logs.